# Computing the norm of $\varphi ((x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x_n$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $p,q>1$, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$ and $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\in l_q$. Show that $\varphi : l_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\varphi ((x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x_n$ is a continuous  linear functional and compute its norm.

**My attempt:**

By Holder's inequality:

$$|\varphi ((x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}})|= \bigg| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x_n  \bigg| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n x_n|  \leq 
\|a\|_q \|x\|_p$$

Then $\varphi$ is continuous and $\| \varphi \| \leq \|a\|_q$.
I'm having trouble to show that $\| \varphi \|  = \|a\|_q$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x_n= {\rm sign}(a_n)|a_n|^{q-1}$.