# $\lVert {x}\rVert_p = \max \{ |\langle x,y \rangle|: \lVert y \rVert_q \leq 1\}$

Tags: inequality

If $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{F}^m, m>1$, then how to use Hölder's Inequality to prove $\lVert {x}\rVert_p = \max \{ |\langle x,y \rangle|: \lVert y \rVert_q \leq 1\}$？

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing the norm of $\varphi ((x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726023/computing-the-norm-of-varphi-x-n-n-in-mathbbn-sum-n-1-infty-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $x,y$ are finite dimensional vectors, if not, you need to specify what they exactly are.

Firstly, Holder's inequality gives 
$$\|x\|_p\ge\|x\|_p\|y\|_q\ge \langle x,y\rangle,\forall \|y\|_q \le 1$$
Then, simply take $y = \frac{x}{\|x\|_q}$.

Comment: If you take $y=\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert_q}$, then $\lVert y \rVert_q=1$, but how you achieve the equality in $\lVert x \rVert_p \lVert y \rVert_q \geq \langle x,y \rangle$?