# How to calculate the norm-$p$ distance between point and hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces

I want to calculate the distance between a point $y\in \mathbb{R}^N$ to the hyperplane defined by $a^Tx=0$. Here, the **distance metric** is the general distance, i.e., $d(x,y)=|| y-x ||_p$, where $p>0$.

The minimum distance problem is equivalent to solve the following problem
\begin{align}
\min_x || y-x ||_p, ~~\text{s.t.} ~ a^Tx=0,
\end{align}
where $x,y,a\in \mathbb{R}^N$.

I read some references, it said that the problem above has the minimum distance of
\begin{align}
\frac{|a^Ty|}{||a||_q}
\end{align}
where $1/p+1/q=1$. The case for $p=2$ can be found and proved easily in the textbook, but how can we prove the general case?

---

As Anne Bauval commented, I notice there is a question [Distance between point and linear Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253953/distance-between-point-and-linear-space). It has the conclusion for arbitrary kernal $f$, and in my case $f(x) = a^Tx$. Maybe we can have some ideas from that question.

Here, I explicitly write the type of norm to avoid confusions. Based on a previous question: [Distance between point and linear Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253953/distance-between-point-and-linear-space), the minimum distance is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{|a^T y|} {|| f ||_{op}}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
|| f ||_{op} = \sup_x \frac{| f(x)|}{\| x\|_p}
\end{align}
In my case, $|| f ||_{op}=\| a\|_q$.

Comment: Express $x-y$ as a component along $a$ and a component perpendicular to $a$. Evaluate $\|x-y\|^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat. Yes, for the case of $p=2$, the result is clear. The general norm-$p$ is not easy.

Comment: I should read the question before commenting...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distance between point and linear Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253953/distance-between-point-and-linear-space)

Comment: @Anne Bauval, it is a little similar, but it seems that the post question focuses on the L2 distance?

Comment: Nono it is for any norm. Your post is more than similar. It is a particular case.

Comment: How can we intepret the norm of a function, i.e., $||f||$?

Comment: $||f||=sup |f(x)|/|x|$

Comment: Thus, based on this definition, the denominator, i.e., $||f||$, becomes independent of $q$?

Comment: In your context, $f(y)=a^Ty$ and $\|f\|$ (as defined above) is equal to $\|a\|_q.$

Comment: @Anne Bauval, if the result in the reference is correct, $||f||$ should be equal to $|| a||_q$, but how to prove it?

Comment: [$\lVert {x}\rVert_p = \max \{ |\langle x,y \rangle|: \lVert y \rVert_q \leq 1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116205)(where $p$ and $q$ have been exchanged).